# how to improve speed in database?

Tags: mysql

I am starting to create my first web application in my career using mysql.

I am going to make table which contain users information (like id, firstname, lastname, email, password, phone number).

Which of the following is better?

1. Put all data into one single table (userinfo).
2. Divide all data by alphabet character and put data into many tables. for example, if user's email id is Joe@gmail.com that put into table (userinfo_j) and if user's email id is kevin@gmail.com that put into table (userinfo_k).

Comment: *if user's email id is Joe@gmail.com that put into table(userinfo_j) and if user's email id is kevin@gmail.com that put into table(userinfo_k).* I'm just going to go ahead and say the `PHP` tag is implied here...

Comment: You should always try to put all data that has the same structure into the same table - then speedwise you optimize by selecting only what you really need and not to forget **indexes**

Comment: The second method is called **partitioning** and MySQL can do it internally. But it depends on what queries will be run against that table, as you can partition by many algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to sound condescending, but I think you should spend some time reading up on database design before tackling this project, especially the concept of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization), which provides consistent and proven rules for how to store information in a relational database.

In general, my recommendation is to build your database to be easy to maintain and understand first and foremost. On modern hardware, a reasonably well-designed database with indexes running relational queries can support millions of records, often tens or hundreds of millions of records without performance problems.

If your database has a performance problem, tune the query first; add indexes second, buy better hardware third, and if that doesn't work, you may consider a design that makes the application harder to maintain (often called denormalization).

Your second solution will almost certainly be slower for most cases.

Relational databases are really, really fast when searching by indexed fields; searching for "email like 'Joe@gmail.com'" on a reasonable database will be too fast to measure on a database with tens of millions of records.

However, including the logic to find the right table in which to search will almost certainly be slower than searching in all the tables.

Especially if you want to search by things other than email address - imagine finding all the users who signed up in the last week. Or who have permission to do a certain thing in your application. Or who have a @gmail.com account.

So, the second solution is bad from a design/maintenance point of view, and will almost certainly be slower.

Comment: Shouldn't adding indexes come before buying better hardware? (Imho adding indexes should be included in step one (query tuning))

Comment: I agree - I will rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

First one is better. In second you will have to write extra logic to find out which table you will start looking into. And for speeding up the search you can implement indexers. Here I suppose you will do equal operations more often rather than less than or more than operations so you can try implementing indexer with Hash. For comparison operations B-Tree are better.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, the first one is better. Specially if you need to add other tables in your database and link them to user´s table, as the second one will soon get impossible to work and create relationships when your  number of tables increase.